# JQuery Change Property of Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datatables

Hi there I have a data table created in JQuery as shown..

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
        scrollY: 300,
        paging: false
    });
    var settings = table.fnSettings();
    console.log(settings)
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to modify the property scrollY to have a different value such as 400. I would like to do this after initialisation. However, the variable `settings` is apparently null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using `$('#example').DataTable()` ...note capital `D` ... there are 2 versions of plugin function. The lowercase version requires accessing the api() method

Comment: I get: `Uncaught TypeError: table.fnSettings is not a function`.

Comment: also may be a version issue... what version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are being returned a `NULL` value is because jQuery datatables can't find your table.

You need to define the table HTML on the page accordingly, above your javascript, based on the data you are to display. It needs to follow the following format (including the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

```html
<table id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
        scrollY: 300,
        paging: false
    });
    var settings = table.fnSettings();
    alert(settings)
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wynrj8vh/

Also, according to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY), you need to pass a string value to ScrollY:

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "scrollY": "200px"
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to define your table in HTML:

```
<table id="example">
```

And then:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable();
oSettings = table.fnSettings();

if(oSettings != null) {
   table.fnDraw();
}//if
```